# how to interpret the details graph for a stage in spark ui

Tags: apache-spark, spark-ui

I am seeing this details graph in the spark ui:

[image]

I have couple of questions regarding this graph:

1- Why Schedular delay and Task deserialization take so long compared to computing time? Does this mean something is wrong with job optimization (with my spark script)?

2- As I understand, each row corresponds to an executor (see `1/10.42.3.34`, `2/10.42.4.160` etc. on the left column). Each executor has 3 cores but some rows contain 2 "colored bar"s while some contain 3 bars. Why is that? Is each colored bar for a specific core/task? Then why have 2 bars while having 3 cores? Does that mean 1 core did not work at all?

3- Colored bars in a row never start at the same position. What does that mean? Does this tell us that, although run in parallel, tasks do not start at the same time?

4- Same applies to the ending of the bars.

5- Why some bars have a yellow ending (indicating shuffle write time) while others do not?

6- Why some bars have purple ending (indicating result serialization time) while others do not?

7- Why some bars end with yellow followed by purple (both shuffle write and serialization)? What is happening there?

8- At the top of the graph it is saying 2 secs `Across all Tasks`. How is that calculated? When I look at the task durations I don't see a task that takes more than a couple of milliseconds.

[image]

I believe understanding this graph is quite important so any help is appreciated. Cheers.